# Find and change the color of a word in a text box Tkinter

Tags: python, text, tkinter, ide

I am making a development environment type program with python and have a basic working program but I have a problem. I want to highlight certain words like import in a different color, like most development environments do but it wont work!

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from gameplay import *
from tkinter import *
import msvcrt as m
import os

openfileloc = ""

def combine_funcs(*funcs):
    def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in funcs:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
    return combined_func

def load_file():
    rootFd = Tk()
    rootFd.withdraw()
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    data = open(file_path, "r").read()
    txtFd.delete('1.0', END)
    txtFd.insert('1.0', data)
    openfile = data
    openfileloc = file_path

def save_file_dialog():
    rootFd = Tk()
    rootFd.withdraw()
    wr = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".br")
    if wr.name != '':
        wr.write(txtFd.get('1.0', "end"))
        openfileloc = wr.name
    wr.close()
def save_file():
    if os.path.isfile(openfileloc):
        os.remove(file_path)
        wr = open(openfileloc, "w").write(txtFd.get('1.0', "end"))
    else:
        save_file_dialog()

def new_file():
    txtFd.delete('1.0', END)
    openfile = ""
    openfileloc = ""
# HEY STACKOVERFLOW PROBLEM IS HERE
def highlightKeywords():
    text = txtFd,get('1.0', 'end')
    KeywordSet1 = ['import', 'if'] # Hilighted in Yellow
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if KeywordSet[i] in text:
            txtFd.highlight_pattern(KeywordSet1[i], "yellow")

root = Tk()
root.title("GameBox Engine Editior - 0.0a")
menubar = Menu(root)
#Menu
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=new_file)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=load_file)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=save_file)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save as...", command=save_file_dialog)

filemenu.add_separator()

filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

root.config(menu=menubar)
txtFd = Text(root)
txtFd.pack()

root.mainloop()

# THIS IS WHERE I CALL THE FUNCTION
running = True
while(running):
    m.getch()
    highlightKeywords()
```

There are no errors, it just does not work. Can you help me?

Comment: You have a comma instead of a dot when you define text.

The reason why it is valid is because you define a tuple.

Comment: Functions after the call to `mainloop` won't execute until the window has been destroyed. Also, the text widget doesn't have a `highlight_pattern` method.

Comment: You should bind your functions to the text widget to run off a key press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use (from http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

```
text.tag_configure('color', foreground='blue')
text.insert(END, "This is blue\n", 'color')

## you can also use relative position
text.tag_add('color', "1.0", "1.4")
```